# Substitute for TemplateResolver in 3.0.0 version of thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have substituted Thymeleaf 3.0.0 from 2.1.6 version while doing refactoring because of which TemplateResolver and IResourceResolver cannot be resolved to a type.It is deprecated in 3.0.0 version .Can anyone tell me what is the substitute for TemplateResolver in 3.0.0 version.I am not using spring

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose?  My Thymeleaf 3.0 template resolver creation looks like this.

```java
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

    // ...
    // configuration
    // ...

    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: I was using org.thymeleaf.TemplateProcessingParameters and org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.IResourceResolver .These are all deprecated .  What can I use on behalf TemplateProcessingParameters and IResourceResolver .

Comment: Your question is only asking about TemplateResolver.  If you want more information, you need to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `TemplateResolver` for `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`.